# Is there a way to *round* a nearby point into the feasible set?

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry, polygons

Let $P \subset \mathbb R^d$ be a polytope with interior given by $F$-many linear inequalities. Suppose we have a convex problem with feasible set $P$. For example computing the Euclidean projection of some point onto $P$.

Instead of trying to directly solve the problem we run Langrange multipliers on the dual problem. This gives a sequence $\lambda_n \in \mathbb R_+^F$  converging to the dual solution  $\lambda^*$ and a sequence $x_n \in \mathbb R^d$ converging to the primal solution $x^*$.

We know $x^*$ is feasible but   $x_n$ might not be. In practice we never compute  $x^*$ itself  but only  $x_N$ for some very large $N$. Ideally we have theoretical results that say how big we must take $N$ to make the error less than $\epsilon$.

[image]

Doing that, we get an infeasible *approximate solution* $x_N = p$ that we know is distance $\epsilon$ of $x^*$. That means the ball of radius $2 \epsilon$ around $p$ intersects the interior, and we know $x^*$ is somewhere in that intersection.

To get a feasible point near $p$ the obvious thing to do is project onto $P$ . Unfortunately this amounts to solving another problem on domain $P$ and we're back to where we're started!

However we have in fact simplified the problem as any $y^*$ in the red region is feasible with $\|x^* -y^*\| < 2\epsilon$. Is it any easier to find such a $y^*$ than solving the original problem?